# preg_match fails when brackets are added

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

the following is a simplification of a regex i am using. on my development machine both `$pattern1` and `$pattern2` return a match, however on my production machine only `$pattern1` returns a match! clearly the only difference between `$pattern1` and `$pattern2` is that one of them has brackets around a word. however both are valid patterns which should match the given haystack (as far as i know).

```
$pattern1 = '/\<a name="ERROR TEXT"\>\<\/a\>\s*?validated\s*?\<\/span\>\s*?\<\/h1\>/';
$pattern2 = '/\<a name="ERROR TEXT"\>\<\/a\>\s*?(validated)\s*?\<\/span\>\s*?\<\/h1\>/';
$haystack = '- IFCS msg value, BOOKMARKED AS ERROR TEXT -->
          <a name="ERROR TEXT"></a>
             validated</span>
       </h1>

                <!-- START: .formActionHolder -->
                <div class="formActionHolder">';
preg_match($pattern1, $haystack, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

has anyone found this problem before? note that this is not the whole of the regex - this is a simplified version which i have identified as being the problem. in my actual code, the value of 'validated' is not a constant - hence my reason for using brackets to capture the word. of course the patterns have other characters within the parenthesis as well so that i can capture the variable words here. this is just a simplified example which hones in on the problem that i am having with two seemingly fine regexes.

on my development machine i am using php5.3.2 with the pcre 7.8 library and on my production machine i am using php5.2.4 with pcre 7.4.

Comment: Escape the parenthesis: `(validated)` -> `\(validated\)`

Comment: why? there are no parenthesis in the haystack. i want to capture the word 'validated' since it is not a constant

Comment: Are you testing exact isolated code above on both machines?

Comment: @mulllhausen cannot repeat on PHP/4.3.10 Linux either... both versions work

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best methods to parse HTML with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html-with-php) from http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had a thought about the `?(` combination in `$pattern2` so i removed the `?` to make

```
$pattern = '/\<a name="ERROR TEXT"\>\<\/a\>\s*(validated)\s*?\<\/span\>\s*?\<\/h1\>/';
```

and that works!! its very strange - possibly even a bug?

so it looks like the `?(validated)` bit was being interpreted as a conditional subpattern rather than the question mark being used to make the `\s*` ungreedy

that doesn't look like correct behavior to me.

ah well...its a bit of a pain since now my `*` will be greedy. the regex pattern does what i want in this instance though...

thanks for all your helpful comments!

Answer (score 0):

Parenthesis are used for grouping in a php regex and act as such unless you escape them to make them act as the characters themselves.

Comment: I think that is the point - they should both match as there are no `()` characters in the subject string. Indeed, they do both match on [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)...

Comment: i know. i want to capture the word 'validated' since it is not a constant

Comment: @mulllhausen if it is not constant, that regex will not match if it has any value other than `validated`. Would you maybe be better using a [DOM parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) for this job?

Comment: @mulllhausen - you might care to update your question to indicate what problem you are having.  Certainly, on my machine, I get the behaviour I would expect from the regex, i.e. the second pattern matches the string for me and correctly picks up on the grouping.

Comment: @DaveRandom - i appreciate the advice but i am pretty fluent with regexes and all my code is tailored around them so it would be a massive hassle to change to a dom parser. as i said earlier, this example is merely a simplification of my real regex (which has a more involved series of characters in the parenthesis). however this example i have given identifies the problem i have.

Comment: @mulllhausen No worries if you have considered the options and concluded that is the best way to go then fair enough

Comment: @borrible - ok i've put in more details to explain my situation. let me know if its still not clear

Answer (score 0):

are you sure the $pattern2 coundn't match? In my eclipse, it match, show 
 Array ( [0] => validated 
[1] => validated )

Comment: yeah i know! it works fine on my dev machine running php5.3.2 aswell.

Comment: @mulllhausen I cannot repeat this on PHP/5.2.9-2 Win32 or PHP/5.2.17 Win32 - is there any way you could upgrade PHP on the production machine? It's looking to me like this may be some kind of bizarre bug in 5.2.4

Comment: @DaveRandom - a php upgrade would be ideal, actually it was my first thought. but looking into it i realised i would probably need to do a clone of the system to test the upgrade and that is going to be a lot of work :( its really annoying that the dev and prod machines are not using the same versions of things!